# How can I remove construction adhesive from finished wood flooring?

Tags: flooring, removal, adhesive

I was attaching some transition molding to a floor section yesterday using PL proline construction adhesive.  Apparently I did not do as a good a job of policing the edge as I thought, and I have several visible places where excess adhesive has come out.  It is not yet fully cured.  Am I better off scraping it up now or after it cures?

Comment: There's this magical time where PL is cured enough to not smear all over the place when you remove it, but hasn't hardened yet. That's when you want to go after it. Problem is, there's no way to tell when that is. Don't wait till it fully cures though, you'll have a real fight on your hands.

Answer (score 1):

> **Cleanup**
>
> Clean tools and uncured adhesive residue immediately with mineral spirits in a well-ventilated area to the outdoors. Remove cured adhesive by carefully scraping with a sharp-edged tool.

From http://www.loctiteproducts.com/p/pl_ca_prem/directions/Loctite-PL-Premium-Polyurethane-Construction-Adhesive.htm

Answer (score -1):

I found using oven cleaner and a razor knife on PL glue  took it off with no damage to wood floors.

Only spray a little and scrape it off carefully.